# Why I am not able to see the application's icon on my phone or on simulator?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I have copied the icon file into my project and in the plist i have updated the image in icon file section.
I think this is all i need to see the application's icon on phone and on the simulator but i can't.
Do you guys know about anything which could possible go wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: What is the Icon called? What did you enter in your plist?

Comment: See my answer. Basically, it's the name thats important. Make sure to remove the old name from the info.plist file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have got all the obvious correct (you've added the icon file, it's 57x57, it is checked in the project resource list, and the entry in the plist matches the file name etc.) try:

1. In XCode4, click through "Product -> Clean", and
2. In the simulator, "iOS Simulator -> Reset contents and settings"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the app from iphone or simulator? If the app has been previously installed, the icon isn't always replaced.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to set up icons in an iOS app is to use the following names and sizes for your icons:

- **iTunes:** `iTunesArtwork` (512px by 512px)
- **Retina Display (iPhone 4):** `Icon@2x.png` (114px by 114px)
- **iPad:** `Icon-72.png` (72px by 72px)
- **Retina Settings:** `Icon-Small@2x.png` (58px by 58px)
- **iPod touch:** `Icon.png` (57px by 57px)
- **iPad Settings:** `Icon-50.png` (50px by 50px)
- **iPod Settings:** `Icon-Small.png` (29px by 29px)

Adding them into your plist is not important, especially if you are using Xcode 4.  Make sure that you name your icons with the above names. You've indicated in the comments above that you've named your icon `iphone_icon.png`. I suggest taking the following steps:

- Rename the icon to `Icon.png`.
- Remove your app from the device/simulator.
- Run a clean build.

Comment: The name of the icon doesn't matter, so long as it matches. (The exception is "iTunesArtwork", and retina tags.) However I agree that having a good convention (not "iPhone_*"!) is worthwhile.

Comment: I know its was working before with the same name i don;t know what went wrong and where? because i couldn't find anything wrong in here.

Answer (score 0):

Please save your Icon imagename as Icon.png and dimension of Icon.png should be 57*57.

Now, please remove application from iPhone device or Simulator. clean build and all target

Run application again

If you want more help for the Icon in all cases then, you can find sample code of Apple form below link.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Icons/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010442